# What should a pilot do upon reaching a Missed Approach Fix when holding instructions are not given?

Tags: instrument-procedures, missed-approach

Typically, Missed Approach Procedures end with a hold at the Missed Approach Fix. This is written in the textual procedures as something like "direct ABC VOR and hold." The graphical section also depicts the Missed Approach Fix, and the holding pattern relative to that fix, including the inbound course, inbound radial, and outbound course.

However, the ILS 20R approach at John Wayne Airport (KSNA) has only a fix as the last element of the Missed Approach Procedures. The textual procedures say:

> Climb to 3000 on I-SNA LOC south course (196°) to MINOE INT/I-SNA 10.9 DME

The graphical representation of the Missed Approach Fix only shows the radials and DME used to identify the fix. It does not have a depicted holding pattern.

[image: KSNA ILS 30R approach plate]

What should a pilot do upon reaching MINOE, in absence of other ATC instructions?

Comment: Is there an approach procedure starting at MINOE?

Comment: @J.Hougaard there are multiple approaches to KSNA from MINOE. However, they are all for runway 2L, not 20R. Two of them have circling minimums, though they are higher that the S-ILS 20R minimums on the ILS 20R approach.

Comment: @BillyClarke Out of curiosity,.are you asking because you found yourself in that situation? Missed approach, headed to MINOE and no one told you what to do next? That would be highly unusual considering how busy KSNA is.

Comment: @JuanJimenez yes, but only virtually. For purposes of IFR training, I was flying this approach on PilotEdge, went missed, and realized I would not have known what to do when I got to MINOE. The virtual controller gave me vectors for another approach, but I am interested to know what the correct full missed approach procedure is. Regardless of the improbability of needing to fly the full missed approach procedure, we have holds at the missed approach fix for a reason, and I’m wondering why it’s not depicted or described here.

Comment: @BillyClarke Yes, except we also don't have holds for good reasons too. The only way to fly holding patterns with RNAV that generally doesn't have holding pattern capability is manually. In that case the RNAV will only give you guidance for the inbound track, the rest is up to you. Were you specifically practicing an RNAV approach? What the controller did is what would be expected if you were.

Answer (score 1):

The clip doesn't show it, but you must be looking at an RNAV approach chart for 20R. The ILS charts for 20R show the holding pattern in the plates. Since RNAV states "Radar Required" if the pilot doesn't get further instructions he/she should immediately ask for them.

Comment: I am looking at the ILS Rwy 20R at KSNA, not the RNAV approach chart. It has a holding pattern at the _alternate_ missed approach fix, but not the regular missed approach fix.